# Understanding ratio between precision and recall

Tags: precision-recall, confusion-matrix

I have a naive question regarding the ratio of precision and recall. When I build the model, I am able to get precision and recall. Later, I could use this model to make perditions, which is `val_pred`. Assuming everything stays the same, that means `ground_truth` value is `val_truth = val_pred * Precision/Recall`.

In that case, will that encourage me of building a higher precision and low recall model in order to inflate `val_truth`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As it follows from their formulas, their ratio is simply N(the class in the true classification)/N(the class in the prediction)

Comment: @ttnphns, yes, that is my understanding. Just wondering in this case, should I use F1 score to pick the `balanced` model or I should just pick the model with highest precision/recall ratio? Since I am also interested to get the `ground truth` value (higher the better) out of model prediction.

Comment: There exist so many various measures of classification performance. Maybe you pick one for you. May read document with formulas on my web page (download "Compare partitions" zip and read there the description of !clasagree macro).